# DataAnnotation é compatível com Json?

Tags: c#, json

Olá! Gostaria de saber se DataAnnotation é compatível com Json, pois estou validando um formulário e gostaria de tirar a dúvida. Estou usando Angular no front e retornando o meu objeto em formato Json, gostaria de validar o retorno desse json(as informações que o usuário digitou nos campos) usando DataAnnotation

Esse é o meu método de adicionar:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Add([FromBody]Sindicate objSindicate)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await _service.Add(objSindicate));
}
```

Essa é a minha classe usando o DataAnnotation.

```
public class SindicateValidator
{
    [Key]

    public Guid SindicateId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome obrigatório!")]
    [MaxLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minímo {0} caracteres")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Razão Social é obrigatório!")]
    [MaxLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minímo {0} caracteres")]
    public string SocialReason { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CNPJ é obrigatório!")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", 
                    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [MaxLength(14, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Login é obrigatório!")]
    [MaxLength(128,ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Senha é obrigatório!")]
    [MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-Mail é obrigatório!")]
    [MaxLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Preencha um E-mail válido!")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool Disable { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? DateDisable { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Exponha o que você já tem e explique melhor o seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Controller` irá validar o `input` independente do `Content-Type` utilizado, porém é importante que o `input` esteja com as notações.

Outro ponto, a `API` por padrão irá serializar o retorno para `JSON`, então não há a necessidade de `serializar` o objeto previamente.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Add([FromBody]SindicateValidator objSindicate)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    var response = await _service.Add(objSindicate);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

Comment: Tobias, devo fazer essa validação nos seguintes métodos: Remove e Update?

Comment: O remove normalmente recebe apenas o id do elemento a ser removido, então não há a necessidade, já o update precisa ser vaiidado.